# 'Character Array' of integers to 'Integer array'

Tags: c, arrays, integer

My Requirement :

Taking some (unknown number) of integers as input from user and store them in a numeric array.

Eg: input:  25 3 4 78. I want them to be stored in a numeric array, say `num` as

```
    num[0] = 25
    num[1] = 3
    num[2] = 4
    num[3] = 78
    . . .
```

What I did :

1. Stored the input in a character array.

   gets(arr);
    //takes input from command prompt and stores in a string
2. Then I'm trying to find spaces and separate the characters, but it turns out that a `double digit number(say,25)` is stored as `2` and `5` but not as `25`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `gets()` is **evil**, use `fgets()` instead. #offtopic

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname I believe that in this case, the explanation of my problem speaks more clearer than my code.

Comment: @SouravGhosh fgets(), according to me is used in files, but here I need to take input from command prompt.

Comment: `"25"` is not stored as `2` and `5`, it is stored as `'2'` and `'5'`, which is an importent difference.

Comment: then someones help you according to your believes @nikhil

Comment: @Yeah, I just read the FM and its clear now. But that doesn't answer my question. I'll refer your answer now.

Comment: ok wait, did you mean command-line arguments?

Comment: Nope, I meant Command Prompt -  the black screen. Did I confuse you?

Comment: Yes, a bit. Next time try `standard input`. That is more common. :)

Comment: Oh sure, Thanks @SouravGhosh. I learnt a lot today! :)

Comment: @nikhil You're welcome. Happy to help. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no "do my homework" site.

Comment: @Olaf I believe there is a huge difference between such homework questions people ask and questions like these. Don't presume that any question without code is only asking you to do its homework. I clearly mentioned what I set out to achieve, I even mentioned what I tried, I asked why it is didn't work and how it is done? I didn't just merely ask a question and left it for you to answer. By the way, that isn't a homework question and remember, all questions needn't have *code*.

Comment: No, but that one should have had. However, you got your answer. I'd recommend to read a C book, as such (reading numbers from a string) is a typical example shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you did not show your code, I'll also not provide any code, but I'll be more than happy to provide you with the flow-chart.

1. Define one array large enough (maybe change to dynamic allocation later).
2. Take the input from user (*not command line arguments*) using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
3. use [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize the input using space  as delimiter.
4. If a non-NULL token is received, use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert the token to `int` or `long`.
5. If `strtok()` returned NULL means you've got all the tokens and the input is empty, finish up, you got your `int` array.

Comment: Cool! Will give it a try! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh it worked.

Comment: @Olaf Stop trolling and stop flagging normal questions as homework questions and off-topic. If you are too concerned and worried about quality of SO, then please bear in mind that comments like the one you made here also have same, if not, no value like those off-topic questions which you seems to be so concerned about.